# Making a batch file for a Linux system?

Tags: linux, batch-file

Quick backstory: I'm a graduate student, and I know very little (read: almost nothing) about batch files. A collaborator at another university came to me and told me to create a batch file for a supercomputer which runs on a Linux system. After googling, it looks like a batch file is technically only for Windows systems, and the Linux equivalent is a "shell script". I talked to my collaborator about this, and he's insistent that it should be a batch file, not a shell script, even though it's a Linux system.

Is there something I'm missing here, or is there some way to make a batch file for Linux? There is a language barrier, so I wonder if that's part of the problem. Thanks, and sorry for such an elementary question.

Comment: Technically, a "batch file" is instructions for "batch processing" which is any non-interactive compute job. It only came to mean a DOS command.com or cmd.exe script when Windows became the only OS most people knew about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "batch" may refer to two different things, maybe that is the issue here:

- the MS-Windows batch command processor, some very primitive and limited, non-interactive shell environment
- "batch processing" which simply means non-interactive processing of work items or jobs

You are right that the (very) rough equivalent to an MS-Windows batch script is a shell script in unixoid systems (so Linux too). However it should be pointed out that there are many very different types of shell environments you can use, so you have a huge flexibility here.

Considering the two alternative meanings above I could imagine that what is meant is "a script that does batch processing". Usually it is of less importance which specific type of language is chosen for that.

Comment: And it is *still* a batch job if it is a Perl, Python or Ruby script instead of Bash.

Comment: @ZanLynx With "different shell environments" I primarily referred to different shells, but indeed you are right, it is also possible to implement such a script using one of the many scripting environments.

Answer (score 3):

The *nix equivalent would be a shell script. For example, Ubuntu's default shell is bash.

[BASH Programming Introduction](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) might prove a worthy read.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer already noted, scripts of command line commands are called ["batch files"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) on Windows, but the term also means [non-interactive processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing) in general.

Since the context was some sort of a supercomputer, there's a possibility that a "batch file" means something specific to the system, not just a generic shell script/program.

Either that, or they are just very insistent on using uncommon terminology.